# I want to run a function that creates images through a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, image, loops, spyder

[This is a screenshot of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EtDp.png)I'm really new to python and I would appreciate any help or recommendations for my problem.
So I created a few really simple lines of code that merge two images next to each other, but now I want to do that operation for a list of 80 pairs of images, that I have already put into a 80 x 2 dataframe using pd.read_excel from pandas. Any suggestions, even if just about where to search to find out more, are greatly appreciated, since I'm just stuck as to where to look.

```
 from PIL import Image
import os
os.chdir("/Users/someone/Documents/stimuli_final")

img = Image.open("/Users/me/Documents/StimuliOnly/1_5_1_n1.bmp")
img = img.resize((1280, 1280))
img1 = Image.open("/Users/me/Documents/StimuliOnly/1_10_1_n2.bmp")
img1 = img1.resize((1280, 1280))
bi = Image.new("RGBA", (2760, 1280), ("#808080"))
bi.paste(img, (0,0,1280,1280))
bi.paste(img1, (1480,0,2760,1280))
bi.save("stim5with14vs28congruent.png")
```

Comment: What are the columns of the DataFrame? Can you add an example of your DataFrame?

Comment: @PyNoob sorry, I added a screenshot to the first line of the description of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added another column to your excel file titled "output file name" and filled that column, you could use something like the following:

```py
def helper(data):
    path1, path2, output_file_name = data["Bild 1"], data["Bild 2"], data["output file name"]
    img = Image.open(path1)
    img = img.resize((1280, 1280))
    img1 = Image.open(path2)
    img1 = img1.resize((1280, 1280))
    bi = Image.new("RGBA", (2760, 1280), ("#808080"))
    bi.paste(img, (0,0,1280,1280))
    bi.paste(img1, (1480,0,2760,1280))
    bi.save(output_file_name)

df.apply(helper, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked out perfectly. Only had to change df.apply to data.apply in the last line.